# Understand "return data_mine['one'] = 1" in a function

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I found the following function in a book I currently read. I understand the function but not why we do `data_mine['one'] = 1` and why we return `data_resampled.one`. Can you explain to me the reason why the author is doing that? Here you can find [citibike.csv](https://github.com/amueller/introduction_to_ml_with_python/blob/master/data/citibike.csv)

```
def load_citibike():
    data_mine = pd.read_csv('citibike.csv')
    data_mine['one'] = 1
    data_mine['starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(data_mine.starttime)
    data_starttime = data_mine.set_index("starttime")
    data_resampled = data_starttime.resample("3h").sum().fillna(0)
    return data_resampled.one

citibike = load_citibike()
citibike.head()

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 3))
xticks = pd.date_range(start=citibike.index.min(), end=citibike.index.max(),
                       freq='D')
plt.xticks(xticks, xticks.strftime("%a %m-%d"), rotation=90, ha="left")
plt.plot(citibike, linewidth=1)
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Rentals")
```

Comment: It actually works fine for me. I just don't understand why 1 is added and defined as return value.

Comment: We can tell you *what* that code does, but only speculate *why* the author does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author is making use of the fact that when you `groupby.func()` the column name remains unchanged, though the values change.

So in this case, though the column `'one'` is initially a column of all 1s, the resulting returned column is the total number of observations that fell within that 3hour time bucket. (IMO, the name should be changed to reflect what the column truly represents.)

---

Here's the illustration:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'starttime': pd.date_range('2018-01-01', freq='15min', periods=20)})

df['one'] = 1
print(df.head())
#            starttime  one
#0 2018-01-01 00:00:00    1
#1 2018-01-01 00:15:00    1
#2 2018-01-01 00:30:00    1
#3 2018-01-01 00:45:00    1
#4 2018-01-01 01:00:00    1

df['starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.starttime)
df_starttime = df.set_index("starttime")
df_resampled = df_starttime.resample("3h").sum().fillna(0)

print(df_resampled)
#                     one
#starttime               
#2018-01-01 00:00:00   12
#2018-01-01 03:00:00    8
```

---

As an aside, the function would be far clearer if equivalently written as

```
def load_citibike():
    df = pd.read_csv('citibike.csv')
    df['starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.starttime)
    return df.set_index('starttime').resample('3H').size().fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`data_mine['one'] = 1` makes all values of the column - 'one' (if it exists already) to 1. If it does not exist already, you just appended a new column `['one']` with all values 1 in `data_mine`.

Hope this makes you understand the function better.

Answer (score 0):

`data_resampled` and `data_mine` are both pandas' `DataFrame`s.

As you can see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#attribute-access), you can create a new attribute only by setting `my_data_frame["key"] = value` (or using another intialization method), but can access it once it has been created by doing `my_data_frame.key`.